# Google captcha block button input submit

Tags: html, recaptcha

I have a problem with the google captcha V2. It works perfectly. The problem is I'm not able to click on the submit input to validate my form.

```html
<form method="post" action="xxxxxxx">
    <div class="champ_de_connexion">
        <span id="label_connexion">    
            <input type="email" name="email_connexion" id="email_connexion" required/>
        </span>
        <span id="label_connexion">
            <input type="password" name="pass_connexion" id="pass_connexion" required/>
        </span>
            
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
            
        <span>
            <input type="submit" value="aa" />
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my web page head, I have this:'

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

To validate my form, I have to click on input type email or password and then press enter.

Comment: your missing the end of your </form> tag?

Comment: I had a problem with the editor of stackoverflow but i have it :)

Comment: What have you tried? Does it work without the RECAPTCHA API? Any error messages?

Comment: @Fatih, It is a problem in the side of HTML not in my server ... I don't know if Google disabled the action of the submit input

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury, without the captcha it works fine

Comment: Is your site using Https?

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury   Yes, in Https :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I had to delete this from my CSS:

transform-origin:0 0;

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check

1. The script must be loaded using the HTTPS protocol ([docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display))
2. Remove all none needed HTML, just have a submit button within the form post to begin with for testing
3. Check error messages in debug console, it could be something simple that your site key is wrong.
4. Check network browser options and see if any events are being fired on click.

Comment: @Joshhua I did what you said and I finaly got the problem. In my Css I used  transform-origin:0 0; And it seems that Google does not like that :)

Comment: Add that into a post and you can accept your own answer :) good job